# location.reload() doesn't work well

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-mvc

***this issue occasionally occurred***

Clicked the grey button "添加标签" in below page, inputed the tag name and submit it. 
[image]
[image]

The submit action will refresh this page and show this tag in the page as below:
[image]

the javascript code of submit action is :

```
function tagSubmit(){
var tagName = $("#tagName").val();
jQuery.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/m/tag/add",
    data : {"taskId":taskId,"tagName":tagName},
    dataType : "json",
    success: function (msg) {  //1/0
        if (msg == 1){
            location.reload();
        }else {
            alertWarning("添加失败");
        }
    }
});
}
```

the Controller.java is :

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/m/tag")
public class TagController extends ControllerBase {

@Autowired
TagService tagService;

@RequestMapping(value = "/add",method = RequestMethod.POST)
@ResponseBody
public int add(@RequestParam(value = "taskId") long taskId    ,@RequestParam("tagName")String tagName){


    boolean flag = tagService.addTag(tagName.trim(),taskId) ;

    return flag?1:0;

}
}
```

the ERROR occurred after I clicked the submit button :
[image]

The url `http://172.16.1.5:9082/m/rule/unScheduleRule?` must require the parameter "taskId" :

```
@RequestMapping(value = "unScheduleRule", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView unScheduleRule(@RequestParam(value = "taskId") long taskId, ModelMap modelMap) {
    Task task = taskService.getById(taskId);
    ModelAndView view = null;
```

How can I fix it ?

add the param `required = false` into the below code ?

```
public ModelAndView unScheduleRule(@RequestParam(value = "taskId",required=false) long taskId, ModelMap modelMap)
```

But if the taskId is not offered ,this page won't work well !!!

***It just occasionally occurred*** ,this makes me very confused

Comment: It may or may not be related, but you're telling jQuery that you're expecting to see a JSON response, but then you're testing for just a number (1). If you're just sending back a 1 or a 2, you probably don't want to treat it as JSON, as a JSON document is supposed to have a top level object or array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `event.preventDefault()` to stop form from submitting and you can submit it by AJAX.

> If this method is called, the default action of the event will not be triggered.

```
function tagSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
```

Docs: http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/